# $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^{2}+x^{2}-2xR\cos\left(i\frac{\pi}{n-1}\right)}})$

Tags: calculus, summation

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^{2}+x^{2}-2xR\cos\left(i\frac{\pi}{n-1}\right)}}\right)$$

Is there a closed form solution for this? This is not a question of a test, so I have no reason to believe so but I encountered it while solving a self made Physics Problem.

The graph for this shows the expected behavior I wanted from the physics problem.
Graph for $n=200$(Graph does not change much even up to a larger value like 2000):
[image]

I will try to explain how I came upon this without involving the physics.

First of all we have a Semi-Circle in the positive Y Direction centered at the Origin with Radius R.
Then I have divided the circle into n points placed at an equal distance from each other.

Example for $n=7$ case
[image]

The points will have the following values:
$$\left(R\cos\left(a\frac{\pi}{n-1}\right),R\sin\left(a\frac{\pi}{n-1}\right)\right), 0\leq a\leq n-1,a \in \mathrm Z $$

Then we have to choose a arbitrary point on the X-Axis, let's say Point $P(x,0)$

Now the main problem is to add the reciprocal of the distance of Point $P$ from all the $n$ points on the circle. Which comes out to be:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^{2}+x^{2}-2xR\cos\left(i\frac{\pi}{n-1}\right)}}$$
The factor of $\frac{1}{n}$ is added by me to adjust the value for $x=0$.
Now I just need to take the limit as $n \to \infty$

Of course there could be a better approach for this, Complex Numbers  for example but I have not studied them much.

Comment: hello! could you provide more context of the original problem and also clarify the notations used here, thanks.

Comment: @Ercanayan The original is a Self Made Physics problem, But I have explained the main Steps here. And could you inform me which notations are ambiguous I would change them.

Comment: You can write this in terms of [complete elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind)

Comment: @Andrei Well I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The $1/n\sum ...$ is a Riemann sum, which you write as an integral $$\int_0^1\frac 1{\sqrt{R^2+x^2-2Rx\cos(\pi\varphi)}}d\varphi$$

Comment: @Andrei Thank you for the answer, I was able to write it in terms of Complete Elliptic Integrals.